# how to convert an excel file into a text file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, text

hi :) i'm hoping someone can help me with an issue that i can't seem to solve. i have filtered data from numerous excel files and put the required data into one excel file. however, i need this data to be in a text file, so i would like to ask if anyone could tell me how to convert this excel file with the filtered data into a text file or any way in which i can just insert the filtered data from my new excel file into my text file. the excel file is well over 500 rows so i cant just use the f.write and manually type in the data.
below is the code used to filter the data into a new excel file as well as the code to create the new text file in which i would like to store this data. the data containts labels and values e.g. country name and the amount of air pollution in that country (i just dont know how to get the values from the excel file into the text file)

```
country_list = ['Malta', 'Germany', 'France', 'Italy', 'Poland'] #specific 
info required
df_full_filtered = df_full[df_full.Country.isin(country_list)]
print(df_full_filtered.shape)
print(df_full_filtered.Country.unique()) 
print(df_full_filtered.head(10))

f= open("C:/Users/julia/OneDrive/Documents/python assignment/European Air 
Quality.txt","w+")
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: One option is [to_string()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html). It is unclear what your requirements are for the text file.

Comment: the excel file contains labels and values. i have an assignment wherein i need to put the filtered data in a text file so the requirements for the file is to contain the labels and the values

Comment: By Excel file do you actually mean the CSV file?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question is unclear: What specifically is wrong with your current output? `to_csv()` writes to a csv-delimited text file. Is the csv format you need to change? The file format? The delimiter?

Comment: when i run that part of the code is produces the filtered excel file as well as the new text file. however the text file is empty as i dont know what code to use to insert the data from the excel file into the newly made text file

Comment: Well the CSV file *is* a text file, its not an Excel file (it may *open* in Excel but unlike a true Excel file it would also open in Notepad)

Comment: What does your ideal output look like? This question is unanswerable without more information

Comment: i'd like to apologize for the vagueness of my question- im new to python and not 100% sure on how it works - even after hours of watching tutroials online. @noah ideally, after running the code, i would end up with a text file with the data that i have filtered. a text file containing the labels (country name/ type of air pollution etc) as well as their values (the amount of pollution etc.)

Comment: even after creating a path for the csv file, it doesnt show up in my documents

Comment: I don't quite understand your ask. Are you asking how to dump your dataframe into a CSV file? you can do `df_full_filtered.to_csv(path=r"C:/Users/julia/OneDrive/Documents/python assignment/European Air 
Quality.txt")`

Comment: thanks @Simon! that's exactly what i wanted to do! i managed to make a txt file instead of a csv file by using th ecode u gave me and just replacing both '.csv' to '.txt. and now i have my text file:)